# windows 8.1 cannot detect the laptop camera

Tags: windows-8.1, camera

I upgraded my Windows 7 to Windows 8.1 but now my laptop cannot detect its camera. Every time I click the camera icon, a message comes out that I should connect a camera. My laptop has a built-in camera on it. What should I do?

Comment: Did you verify the hardware was Windows 8.1 compatible (drivers available) before upgrading?

Answer (score 0):

*Need more detail about make and model.*

I think this is because the PC doesn't have the **drivers** for it.

As a check, go to **Device Manager**(type device manager in Start and click the first result) and find the webcam device-if there's a exclamation mark next to it then it indicates an absence of driver.

Firstly make sure your **Windows Updates** are the latest, as some drivers are provided through it.

If you have installed all the latest updates but the camera is still not detected, then download the drivers for it via your **manufacturer's website**.

For example, for an Acer laptop, you go to Acer Downloads to search for and download your integrated webcam driver for Windows 8.1.

There are also many other ways but I'll explain if the above 2 methods don't work.